# How to replace substring between two other substrings in python?

Tags: python, string

I have a corpus of text documents, some of which will have a sequence of substrings. The first and last substrings are consistent, and mark the beginning and the end of the parts I want to replace. But, I would also like to delete/replace all substrings that exist between these first and last positions.

```
origSent = 'This is the sentence I am intending to edit'
```

Using the above as an example, how would I go about using 'the' as the start substring, and 'intending' as the end substring, deleting both in addition to the words that exist between them to make the following:

```
newSent = 'This is to edit'
```

Comment: you'll need to be a lot clearer on the rules for defining these substrings, if 'the' and 'intending' are always the defining words, then this is trival via `str.split()` of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex replacement here:

```
origSent = 'This is the sentence I am intending to edit'
newSent = re.sub(r'\bthe((?!\bthe\b).)*\bintending\b', '', origSent)
print(newSent)
```

This prints:

```
This is  to edit
```

The "secret sauce" in the regex pattern is the tempered dot:

```
((?!\bthe\b).)*
```

This will consume all content which does *not* cross over another occurrence of the word `the`.  This prevents matching on some earlier `the` before `intending`, which we don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
s_list = origSent.split()
newSent = ' '.join(s_list[:s_list.index('the')] + s_list[s_list.index('intending')+1:])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you missed an = sign in that second line. Should it say "newSent = ' '.join . . ."

Comment: Corrected the answer